# SQL query to select data between dates does not show last date

Tags: mysql

im using a query to get data between dates but for some reason it does not pull the data of the last date selected here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE status = "completed" AND orderdate >= ? AND orderdate <= ? ORDER BY orderid DESC
```

Im using is equal to or less then... but still?

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: did you try using `between` and what is the datatype of `orderdate` and your input start and end date

Comment: orderdateis a datetime but um passing in $dateTo = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['dateTo'])); just a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE status = "completed" AND date(orderdate) >= date(?) AND date(orderdate) <= date(?) ORDER BY orderid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me also, but in my case instead of passing a `date` I was querying using a `datetime` variable, Please make sure you are querying with `date` variable only.

Make sure that `orderdate` is `date` as well as your query parameter is also `date`, or use appropriate function to convert them in date, than query.

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are actually datetimes - so you are actually, in the case of the upperbound, saying "12 midnight" on whichever date you choose. Hence, if it tries to test a value at say 10am in the morning, it fails as being outside the range.

Either set the upperbound date one day forward, or explicitly only test the date part of the datetime...